# Custom Admin URL problem in Chrome

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-panel, chrome-browser

So, I set a custom admin URL in the local.xml and everything works fine in Firefox, but when I log-in through Chrome from http://www.example.com/customurl I land on a 404 site in the admin panel.

I can use the admin navigation bar and use everything as normal, it's just annoying landing here:

[image]

first and other employees might think something is wrong.

Another thing I found out is, that if I use http://www.example.com/admin/customurl it works as it should.

Any suggestions?

Comment: not cache by any chance?

Comment: Please add your `local.xml` code in question.

Comment: Just the normal code to change your /admin location:  `<frontName><![CDATA[customurl]]></frontName> ` @Anja Cache has been cleared - both browser and magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this with a permanent redirect from the normal link (/customurl) to the working link (/admin/customurl), if anyone has a solution working with the normal link, feel free to share.